# Kernel_task using 300% CPU time, high fan speed and slow computer in MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, memory, performance

My MacBook Pro has become slow lately. Activity monitor shows kernel task is using around 300% CPU. The fan is always on at high speed.

Below are the details of my computer:

- Macbook Pro 13-inch, Mid 2012;
- Processor  2.5 GHz Intel Core i5;
- Memory  4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3;
- Graphics  Intel HD Graphics 4000

Please suggest some solutions.

I tried resetting the SMC a few times.

### Console Log

```
Jun  5 17:17:11 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: Resetting IOCatalogue.
Jun  5 17:17:28 Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.kextcache[212]: rebuilding /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.kext.caches/Startup/kernelcache
Jun  5 17:17:30 Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.kextd[11]: Load com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink failed; removing personalities from kernel.
Jun  5 17:17:31 Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.kextd[11]: Load com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter failed; removing personalities from kernel.
Jun  5 17:17:32 Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.kextd[11]: Load com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient failed; removing personalities from kernel.
Jun  5 17:17:33 Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.kextd[11]: Load com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP failed; removing personalities from kernel.
Jun  5 17:17:34 Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.kextd[11]: Load com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor failed; removing personalities from kernel.
Jun  5 17:17:34 Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.kextd[11]: Load com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics failed; removing personalities from kernel.
Jun  5 17:17:35 Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.kextd[11]: Load com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver failed; removing personalities from kernel.
Jun  5 17:17:36 Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.kextd[11]: Load com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU failed; removing personalities from kernel.
Jun  5 17:17:37 Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.kextd[11]: Load com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler failed; removing personalities from kernel.
Jun  5 17:17:37 Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.kextd[11]: Load com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController failed; removing personalities from kernel.
Jun  5 17:17:39 Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.kextd[11]: Load com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC failed; removing personalities from kernel.
Jun  5 17:17:39 Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.kextd[11]: Load com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP failed; removing personalities from kernel.
Jun  5 17:17:41 Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.kextd[11]: Load com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess failed; removing personalities from kernel.
Jun  5 17:17:42 Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.kextd[11]: Load com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager failed; removing personalities from kernel.
Jun  5 17:17:42 Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.kextd[11]: Load com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet failed; removing personalities from kernel.
Jun  5 17:27:50 Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local com.apple.kextcache[244]: Created prelinked kernel /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.kext.caches/Startup/kernelcache.
Jun  5 17:27:51 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: Kext loading now disabled.
Jun  5 17:27:51 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: Kext unloading now disabled.
Jun  5 17:27:51 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: Kext autounloading now disabled.
Jun  5 17:27:51 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: Kernel requests now disabled.
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: Longterm timer threshold: 1000 ms
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: PMAP: PCID enabled
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: PMAP: Supervisor Mode Execute Protection enabled
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: Darwin Kernel Version 13.2.0: Thu Apr 17 23:03:13 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.100.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: vm_page_bootstrap: 939686 free pages and 100698 wired pages
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: kext submap [0xffffff7f807a9000 - 0xffffff8000000000], kernel text [0xffffff8000200000 - 0xffffff80007a9000]
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: zone leak detection enabled
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: "vm_compressor_mode" is 4
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: standard timeslicing quantum is 10000 us
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: standard background quantum is 2500 us
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: mig_table_max_displ = 74
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: TSC Deadline Timer supported and enabled
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=1 LocalApicId=0 Enabled
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=2 LocalApicId=2 Enabled
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=3 LocalApicId=1 Enabled
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=4 LocalApicId=3 Enabled
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=5 LocalApicId=255 Disabled
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=6 LocalApicId=255 Disabled
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=7 LocalApicId=255 Disabled
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=8 LocalApicId=255 Disabled
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for TMSafetyNet
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Safety net for Time Machine (TMSafetyNet)
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for Sandbox
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Seatbelt sandbox policy (Sandbox)
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for Quarantine
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Quarantine policy (Quarantine)
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: Copyright (c) 1982, 1986, 1989, 1991, 1993
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: The Regents of the University of California. All rights reserved.
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: MAC Framework successfully initialized
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: using 16384 buffer headers and 10240 cluster IO buffer headers
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: AppleKeyStore starting (BUILT: Apr 17 2014 23:36:27)
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: IOAPIC: Version 0x20 Vectors 64:87
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: ACPI: sleep states S3 S4 S5
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement: Turbo Ratios 0046
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement: (built 23:35:25 Apr 17 2014) initialization complete
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: pci (build 23:24:05 Apr 17 2014), flags 0x63008, pfm64 (36 cpu) 0xf80000000, 0x80000000
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration begin ]
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: console relocated to 0xf80000000
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration end, bridges 11, devices 15 ]
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: FireWire (OHCI) Lucent ID 5901 built-in now active, GUID 003ee1fffea1d692; max speed s800.
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: mcache: 4 CPU(s), 64 bytes CPU cache line size
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: mbinit: done [64 MB total pool size, (42/21) split]
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: Pthread support ABORTS when sync kernel primitives misused
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: rooting via boot-uuid from /chosen: CE01C8BF-EA58-3180-808C-44150001BB0D
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: Waiting on <dict ID="0"><key>IOProviderClass</key><string ID="1">IOResources</string><key>IOResourceMatch</key><string ID="2">boot-uuid-media</string></dict>
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib kmod start
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless kmod start
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib load succeeded
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless load succeeded
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient: ready
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: Got boot device = IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/SATA@1F,2/AppleIntelPchSeriesAHCI/PRT0@0/IOAHCIDevice@0/AppleAHCIDiskDriver/IOAHCIBlockStorageDevice/IOBlockStorageDriver/APPLE HDD TOSHIBA MK5065GSXF Media/IOGUIDPartitionScheme/Customer@2
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: BSD root: disk0s2, major 1, minor 1
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: BTCOEXIST off 
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: BRCM tunables:
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: pullmode[1] txringsize[  256] txsendqsize[1024] reapmin[   32] reapcount[  128]
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Macintosh HD on device root_device
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: Thunderbolt Self-Reset Count = 0xedefbe00
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::checkStatus - received Status Packet, Payload 2: device was reinitialized
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: pci pause: SDXC
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: VM Swap Subsystem is ON
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: Waiting for DSMOS...
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: IOBluetoothUSBDFU::probe
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: IOBluetoothUSBDFU::probe ProductID - 0x821D FirmwareVersion - 0x0131
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][start] -- completed -- result = TRUE -- 0xdc00 ****
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: **** [BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][start] -- Completed -- 0xdc00 ****
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR: smcReadData8 failed for key LsNM (kSMCKeyNotFound)
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR LsNM kSMCKeyNotFound(0x84) fKeyHashTable=0x0
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: SMC::smcGetLightshowVers ERROR: smcReadKey LsNM failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: SMC::smcPublishLightshowVersion ERROR: smcGetLightshowVers failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: SMC::smcInitHelper ERROR: smcPublishLightshowVersion failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: Previous Shutdown Cause: 5
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: init
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: probe
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: start
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: [IOBluetoothHCIController][staticBluetoothHCIControllerTransportShowsUp] -- Received Bluetooth Controller register service notification -- 0xdc00 
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: [IOBluetoothHCIController][start] -- completed
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: DSMOS has arrived
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: [IOBluetoothHCIController::setConfigState] calling registerService
Jun  5 17:29:35 localhost kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHCIController][protectedBluetoothHCIControllerTransportShowsUp] -- Connected to the transport successfully -- 0x2c40 -- 0x2000 -- 0xdc00 ****
Jun  5 17:29:36 localhost kernel[0]: m_tail has not been written to hardware: m_tail = 0x00000000, hardare tail register = 0x00000060
Jun  5 17:29:39 localhost kernel[0]: IO80211Controller::dataLinkLayerAttachComplete():  adding AppleEFINVRAM notification
Jun  5 17:29:39 localhost kernel[0]: IO80211Interface::efiNVRAMPublished():  
Jun  5 17:29:41 localhost kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
Jun  5 17:29:48 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: createVirtIf(): ifRole = 1
Jun  5 17:29:48 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: in func createVirtualInterface ifRole = 1
Jun  5 17:29:48 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm4331_P2PInterface::init name <p2p0> role 1
Jun  5 17:29:48 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: AirPort_Brcm4331_P2PInterface::init() <p2p> role 1
Jun  5 17:29:48 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: Created virtif 0xffffff8018179000 p2p0
Jun  5 17:29:51 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: flow_divert_kctl_disconnect (0): disconnecting group 1
Jun  5 17:29:51 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Suspend -- 
suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0xdc00 ****
Jun  5 17:29:57 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: IOPPF: AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement mode
Jun  5 17:29:57 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: IOPPF: Sent gpu-internal-plimit-notification last value 14 (rounded time weighted average 14)
Jun  5 17:29:57 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: IOPPF: Sent cpu-plimit-notification last value 19 (rounded time weighted average 19)
Jun  5 17:29:57 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: IOPPF: Sent cpu-idle-plimit-notification last value 60 (rounded time weighted average 60)
Jun  5 17:30:00 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: en3: promiscuous mode enable succeeded
Jun  5 17:32:00 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=229[GoogleSoftwareUp] final status 0x0, allowing (remove VALID) page
Jun  5 17:32:14 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: AppleKeyStore:Sending lock change 0
Jun  5 17:34:12 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: Ethernet [AppleBCM5701Ethernet]: Link up on en0, 100-Megabit, Full-duplex, Symmetric flow-control, Debug [796d,0301,0de1,0300,45e1,0000]
Jun  5 17:34:13 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: AppleBCM5701Ethernet [en0]:       44     600a receivePackets - got vlan packet
Jun  5 17:35:34 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: fsevents: watcher dbfseventsd (pid: 302) - Using /dev/fsevents directly is unsupported.  Migrate to FSEventsFramework
Jun  5 17:36:10 Manishs-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: considerRebuildOfPrelinkedKernel prebuild rebuild has expired
```

Comment: Is your Mavericks up-to-date ?

Comment: Look in the Console to see what is it doing?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I think so.

Comment: @Buscar it is doing a lot of things but how do I know which one is taking the most CPU time?

Comment: @Buscar웃 also added a screen shot of system logs on kernel.

Comment: sorry, that is not very readable. Just type kernel (as you did) in the filter window in the Console then select some 50 lines use Copy, and Paste it in here. One more question, do you use disk encryption?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I don't have disk encryption. Done as you said about lines from console.

Comment: There are too many plausible explanations. It could, for example, be a [runaway process](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS147) throttling the kernel. **1)** Please run [Etrecheck](http://www.etresoft.com/etrecheck) and either update your post with the output, or post the contents to [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com) and update with the pastebin link. **2)** have you used any third party utility, such as Onyx to "clean the system"? **3)** Run the following command in Terminal and update your post with it's output: `(pmset -g; echo; pmset -g assertions) | open -a TextEdit`

Answer (score 10):

Check this [solution](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1706948) from macrumors:

1. Go to About this mac under the apple in the upper left and click on More info
2. Click on system report
3. Make a note of what it says after Model Identifier
4. Go to the folder (this can be achieved in Finder using Go>Go to Folder (cmd-shift-g) ) `/System/Library/Extensions/IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/Contents/Plugins/ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin.kext/Contents/Resources`
5. Find the name from step 3 and move it to a folder that you can find
   again if needed.
6. Restart and you’re done

Comment: Seems to work on 10.10 Yosemite Beta, too.

Comment: What if there is no file corresponding to my Model Identifier (MacBookPro10,1)?

Comment: @Gujamin, for that case, ``sudo mv /System/Library/Extensions/IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/ ~`` worked for me.

Comment: I also had to do what Vivek posted just above (I went to the directory in Finder, moved it to desktop, and was asked for my password, that also worked)
*I would love to know what causes this.*

Comment: Neither Christian nor Vivek's suggestion had any effect for me on Yosemite 10.10.3...

Comment: Vivek's suggestion worked for me on Yosemite 10.10.3. I moved it to a sub folder of ~, but that shouldn't matter. I thought it didn't work at first because it took 60 seconds after rebooting to get noticeably quiet. It had to finish cooling down. Also: the only point noticeably hot for me was the metal between the keyboard and the screen.

Comment: What exactly is this solution doing?

Comment: What is your model name doesn't exist there?

Comment: @VivekPandey `mv: rename /System/Library/Extensions/IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/ to  ~  Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 1):

## Re-install OS X system using a Time Machine backup

The easy way is to reinstall OS X and restore using a Time Machine backup.

#### First make shure you have a Time Machine backup.

Time Machine works with any hard disk connected to your computer using USB, FireWire or Thunderbolt.

- Select the Time Machine icon from the Menu.
- Select Open Time Machine Preferences...
- If Time Machine is off, set the slider to on.
- Select the disk you want to use as a Time Machine backup.
- Time Machine will set the hard drive up for backups and will automatically start the first backup within two minutes.

#### Use these steps if you need to erase a disk before installing OS X:

- Before you begin, you need to be connected to the Internet.
- Choose Apple menu > Restart, and then hold down the Command (⌘) and R keys while the computer restarts.
- Select “Disk Utility,” and then click Continue.
  Select your startup disk from the list on the left, and then click the Erase tab.
- From the Format pop-up menu, select Mac OS Extended (Journaled), type a name for your disk, and then click Erase.
- After the disk has been erased, choose Disk Utility > Quit Disk Utility.
- If you’re not connected to the Internet, choose a network from the Wi-Fi menu in the right corner of the menu bar (in the top-right corner of the screen).
  Select Reinstall Mac OS X, click Continue, and then follow the instructions.

#### To restore the complete contents of your hard drive from a Time Machine backup:

- Power up your Mac and hold down the command and R keys to enter the Recovery Partition. Your Mac should boot to a screen that says OS X Utilities.
- Select Restore from Time Machine Backup and click Continue.
- Read the info on the Restore Your System page and click Continue.
- Select your Time Machine backup and click Continue.
- Select the most recent backup of your hard disk and click Continue. Your Mac will then restore the Time Machine backup; once it's done it will restart.

[iMore](http://www.imore.com/how-set-and-restore-time-machine-backup)
[apple.com](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201376)

Comment: This appears to have solved it for me on Yosemite 10.10.3 on rMBP late 2012